Konjunktiv II mit drei infinitiven
Ich lese gerade einen Roman namens Das Parfüm, in dem gibt es einen Satz den ich nicht verstehe:

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen, ...

Ich denke, es ist "verrecken lassen" + Konjunktiv II + Perfekt, aber ich verstehe die Konjugation nicht.
Wenn ich es selbst gesagt hätte, wäre es

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt verrecken gelassen würde, ...

Ich möchte wissen, ob ich den originalen Satz richtig verstehe, ob es Probleme im meinen Satz gibt und was der Unterschied zwischen den beiden ist.
Vielen Dank!

Dieser Satz stammt genau aus dem Absatz, in dem die Geburt des Helden samt dem Tod seiner Mutter erzählt wird:

... Da fängt, wider Erwarten, die Geburt unter dem Schlachttisch zu schreien an. Man schaut nach, entdeckt unter einem Schwarm von Fliegen und zwischen Gekröse und abgeschlagenen Fischköpfen das Neugeborene, zerrt es heraus. Von Amts wegen wird es einer Amme gegeben, die Mutter festgenommen. Und weil sie geständig ist und ohne weiteres zugibt, daß sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen, wie sie es im übrigen schon mit vier anderen getan habe, macht man ihr den Prozeß, verurteilt sie wegen mehrfachen Kindermords und schlägt ihr ein paar Wochen später auf der Place de Grève den Kopf ab.

Hier ist eine etwas vereinfachte Version des fraglichen Satzes, in neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung. (Der Roman erschien bereits 1985, 11 Jahre vor der Rechtschreibreform und daher in "alter" Rechtschreibung)

Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen.

Das »Ding« ist, wie schon erwähnt, ein Kind, nämlich Jean-Baptiste Grenouille, der Held der Geschichte.
Der vereinfachte Satz besteht aus einem Hauptsatz mit dem Verb »zugeben«, bei dem das Akkusativobjekt, das eigentlich vom Verb gefordert wird, durch einen mit »dass« eingeleiteten Konsekutivsatz ersetzt wurde. Diesen Konsekutivsatz kann man wie folgt in einen gewöhnlichen Hauptsatz umwandeln:

Sie würde das Ding bestimmt haben verrecken lassen.

Das Verb an Position 2 ist ein Modalverb. Es drückt eine Möglichkeit aus. Wenn diese Möglichkeit zu einer Wirklichkeit wird, lässt man das Modalverb einfach weg. Dann muss das Hilfsverb an Position 2 vorrücken. An Position 2 steht in einem Hauptsatz aber immer das Verb, das gebeugt wird, daher wird aus der Infinitiv-Form »haben« die gebeugte Form »hat«:

Sie hat das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

Das Hilfsverb haben/hat ist notwendig, um die Zeitform Perfekt zu bilden. Wenn man diesen Satz in die Gegenwart rückt, fällt es weg, und nun rückt »lassen« nach vor und wird zu »lässt«:

Sie lässt das Ding bestimmt verrecken.

Das Verb »lassen« ist eines der wenigen Verben, die neben sich einen reinen Infinitiv stehen haben können. Zu dieser Kategorie gehören alle Modalverben und das Hilfsverb werden, letztes um die Zeitform "Zukunft" zu bilden (»Ich darf einkaufen, ich kann einkaufen, ich muss einkaufen, usw.« Und: »Ich werde einkaufen.«)
Andere Verben, die diesen Trick ebenfalls beherrschen, sind:

Ich gehe einkaufen. (Ankündigung einer zukünftigen Handlung.)
Ich bin einkaufen. (Beschreibung einer aktuellen Tätigkeit.)
Ich lerne einkaufen. Ich trainiere einkaufen. (Die Tätigkeit "Einkaufen" wird hier zum Gegenstand der Tätigkeit "Lernen" bzw. "Trainieren")

Es gibt noch mehr solcher Verben, einige benötigen noch weitere Objekte (»Ich höre dich singen.«) Und eines dieser Verben ist »lassen«:

Ich lasse einkaufen. (Ich veranlasse, dass eine andere Person diese Tätigkeit für mich ausführt.)
Ich lasse die Suppe abkühlen. (Die Suppe kühlt ohne mein Zutun von selbst ab. Das Verb »lassen« drückt hier nicht aus, dass ich das Abkühlen veranlasse, sondern dass ich nichts dagegen unternehme.)

Der Satz »Die Mutter lässt ihren Sohn verrecken«. bedeutet also, dass die Mutter nichts dagegen unternimmt, dass ihr Sohn mitten im Unrat stirbt. Der Sohn stirbt nämlich sicherlich ganz von alleine:

Das Ding verreckt bestimmt.


Und jetzt das Ganze wieder retour:
Das Kind stirbt sicherlich:

Das Ding verreckt bestimmt.

Die Mutter unternimmt nichts dagegen:

Sie lässt das Ding bestimmt verrecken.

(Beachte, das sich das Wort bestimmt hier auf ein anderes Verb bezieht als zuvor. Zuerst: Es ist sicher, dass das Kind stirbt. Dann: Es ist sicher, dass die Mutter nichts dagegen macht.)
Nicht jetzt, sondern in der Vergangenheit:

Sie hat das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

Das ist nicht wirklich passiert, sondern war nur eine Möglichkeit:

Sie würde das Ding bestimmt haben verrecken lassen.

Das wäre an dieser Stelle auch möglich gewesen:

Sie hätte das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

Aber Patrick Süskind hat in seinem Buch absichtlich etwas sperrigere Konstruktionen als ein Stilmittel verwendet, daher entschied er sich für die Version mit dem Wort »würde«.
Nächste Verkomplizierungsstufe: der Konsekutivsatz

Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen.

Und am Ende wird das noch in einen Schachtelsatz verpackt:

Und weil sie geständig ist und ohne weiteres zugibt, dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen, wie sie es im übrigen schon mit vier anderen getan habe, macht man ihr den Prozess, verurteilt sie wegen mehrfachen Kindermords und schlägt ihr ein paar Wochen später auf der Place de Grève den Kopf ab.

Die letzte Transformation ist dann nur noch der Wechsel von neuer zu alter Rechtschreibung.

Noch ein paar Worte zum folgenden Vorschlag:

Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt verrecken gelassen würde.

Nein, das ist leider falsch. Grammatisch korrekt wäre diese Version:

Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen würde.

Das heißt aber, dass die Mutter jetzt (in der Gegenwart, während sie verhört wird) nichts gegen das Sterben ihres Sohnes unternehmen würde. Angesichts der drohenden Todesstrafe ist das aber unwahrscheinlich. Zutreffend ist hingegen, dass sie sich schon in der Vergangenheit dazu entschieden hat, ihren Sohn sterben zu lassen. Daher muss auch noch das Hilfsverb haben in die Liste der Verben eingefügt werden.
Allerdings ist diese Kombination von drei Verben im Infinitiv sehr selten, und für gewöhnlich vermeidet man solche Kombinationen. Ich habe oben schon diese Version erwähnt:

Sie hätte das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

Daraus wir als Konsekutivsatz diese beiden möglichen Versionen:

Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt hätte verrecken lassen.
Sie gibt zu, dass sie das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen hätte.


Der Satz nach "sie gibt zu, dass" ist ein Objektsatz / Argumentsatz / Inhaltssatz, aber kein Konsekutivsatz.–  Das Wort "würde" ist ein Hilfsverb zur Bildung eines Konjunktivs, es ist kein Modalverb (Modalverben sind "müssen, dürfen, können..." etc. Ein Unterschied ist dass Modalverben das einzige Verb sein können: "Ich muss in die Stadt" aber nicht ? "Ich würde in die Stadt").

(gemeint war: "der dass-Satz nach "sie gibt zu" ... ist ein Objektsatz etc).

@Hubert Schölnast: Thanks for this great and detailed answer, as always!!

Wäre dies auch eine Möglichkeit: "... dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde verrecken lassen haben,..."

@cruthers: Ja, das ist auch denkbar und es erscheint mir sogar einen etwas geschmeidigeren Sprachfluss zu ergeben, weswegen ich diese Variante sogar bevorzugen würde, aber Herr Süßkind wollte eben vermutlich genau jeden Anschein von Geschmeidigkeit bei der Beschreibung dieser Szene vermeiden.


..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen.

Das ist Konjunktiv II Futur II von verrecken lassen, die Ersatzform des Konjunktiv II Perfekt.

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt hätte verrecken lassen.

Beide bedeuten exakt das gleiche. Es ist eine hypothetische Handlung der Vergangenheit.
Der Grund, warum du den Konjunktiv II Futur II nicht erkannt hast, ist vermutlich, dass den außer Leuten wie Süskind keiner verwendet. Man braucht ihn nämlich nicht, denn die Konjunktiv-II-Formen von haben und sein unterscheiden sich von den Präteritumformen. Damit entfällt die Notwendigkeit, eine Ersatzform zu verwenden.

I believe the most transparent way to understand this sentence is by transforming it. This is the sentence from the book:

dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen

The «haben» and «verrecken lassen» parts have been moved to the Nachfeld. By moving them back to the Mittelfeld, we get the standard word order with the finite verb at the end:

dass sie das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen haben würde

This is a subordinate sentence. We can transform it into a regular main clause with the finite verb in the second position:

Sie würde das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen haben.

The form «würde … haben» is the periphrastic conjunctive of «hat». We can replace it by the analytic conjunctive «hätte»:

Sie hätte das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

This preserves the same meaning as the original sentence. Now we can change verb tenses or modes. This will change the meaning, but clarify the structure. The form «hätte … lassen» is a perfect (of the conjunctive preterite). It expresses that the anteriority of the action. We can replace it by a present:

Sie liesse das Ding bestimmt verrecken.

Another transformation is replacing the conjunctive preterite, which expresses that the action did not take place (the irrealis), by the indicative:

Sie hat das Ding bestimmt verrecken lassen.

Or we can replace both the perfect and the conjunctive preterite:

Sie lässt das Ding bestimmt verrecken.

The verb «lassen» + Accusative + another verb expresses the causative. We can remove that as well, thus arriving at:

(Sie lässt bestimmt etwas geschehen, nämlich:) Das Ding verreckt.

Or, in the original perfect of the conjunctive preterite:

(Sie hätte bestimmt etwas geschehen lassen, nämlich:) Das Ding wäre verreckt.


First off, the original sentence is correct, yours is not. This is a very complex construction (and, besides, it is a very bad example of German, grammatically maybe OK but stylistically flawed) and it might help to peel it apart layer by layer:

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen, ...

"verrecken" simply means "to die", but with an implied "under gory circumstances". I had to consult a dictionary for an adequate translation and it came up with "to croak" or "kick the bucket", but I am not really sure of the adequateness of these translations.
So "verrecken lassen" basically means "to let die", but with the implication of "by neglecting ones needs beyond what could be survived" rather then "let one go gracefully".
The construction is "verb+modal verb". Notice, that modal verbs work differently than full verbs:

ich will arbeiten ("wollen": Modalverb)
ich lasse arbeiten ("lassen": Modalverb)
ich wünsche zu arbeiten ("wünschen": Vollverb)
ich beginne zu arbeiten ("beginnen": Vollverb)

The difference between Modalverben (können, mögen, müssen, dürfen, sollen, wollen, lassen) and Vollverben is that the latter express an activity and the second Verb only details this activity: "ich beginne" - "I begin". What I begin with is the detail added by the second Verb: "Ich beginne zu arbeiten" - "I begin to work". With Modalverben this is not the case:
The next layer is the tense. Here is the Präsens Indikativ:

... daß sie das Ding verrecken läßt, ...

now, we put that into Perfekt. Notice, that the common sign of a Partizip Perfekt, the "ge-" prefix is not used here.

... daß sie das Ding hat verrecken lassen, ...

"ge-" startet out as a productive marker for adding "perfectiveness". Verbs come it one of two variants: the ones which describe an ongoing action, for instance "to sleep". When sleeping you sleep in the first minute, in between and also in the last minute. There is no change. Compare that to "to awake": when awakening you are at sleep in the beginning and awake at the end. Then, the activity of "awakening" is over. This quality is what is called "perfective" - a verb which describes an action with a necessary result, a change in state. One more example: compare "to go" (non-perfective, no result, just "ongoing going") with "to come" (perfective, one is not here in the begin but here at the end).
"Ge-", now, was once a productive marker to make verbs (and not only verbs) perfektiv: in modern German yoy have "sitzen" (non-perfective, "to sit") and "sich (hin-)setzen", "niedersetzen" (perfective, "to sit down", "to settle"), etc.. Middle High German had "sitzen" too but for the act of sitting down there was "gesitzen":

ich gesaß (I sat down)

From this the suffix "ge-" went on to become the marker for the Partizip Perfekt ("gehen-ging-gegangen", "stehen-stand-gestanden"), but remnants of this originally much freer use (one could add it to virtually any word) you still see in "Gebrüder", "Gevatter" or "Gewerk" (compare old English "geweorc") and this explains why sometimes the "ge-" is ommitted - the marking of the perfective aspect only has to happen once:

Ich habe dich arbeiten sehen.

This "sehen" looks like an Infinitv, but is in fact the Partizip Perfekt "gesehen" with the "ge-" removed. You may remember this sort of construction from Latin, where it is called Accusativus cum Infinitivus: you work and I have seen you doing so. The object ("dich" of the sentence has an action itself ("arbeiten") and the main action of the subject ("sehen", the "predicate") is carried out by the subject ("ich").
The same is common in passive voice (notice the missing "ge-" in "worden"):

Ich bin reich geworden.
Ich bin gesehen worden.

The sentence in question is actually is not Perfekt but a closely related form: Futur exact or, as Germans also call it, "Futur II". This is the equivalent of "future perfect" in English:

Ich werde gegessen haben.
I will have eaten.

It describes an activity that will have taken place if looked at from some point in the future. So, until now, we have:

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt wird verrecken lassen haben, ...

So, she will have let die the thing in the (hypothetic) history of some future.
Until now we only have Indikativ. In a final step we transform this to Konjunktiv, more correct: Konjunktiv II or Irrealis: you use that to express a possibility which in fact not has come true. She would have let die, but in fact she didn't:

..., dass sie das Ding bestimmt würde haben verrecken lassen, ...


Der Satz mit vier Verben ist in der Tat schwierig. Das erste Verb in der Abfolge, "würde", bildet eine Variante des Konjunktivs. Man kann also vereinfachen: "würde haben" ~ "hätte". Mir ist nicht klar, welche Unterschiede es zwischen diesen Konjunktiven gibt und warum der Autor die genannte umständliche Form gewählt hat.
Die Kombination "hätte" + "verrecken lassen" muss so lauten, obwohl das Perfekt normalerweise das Partizip auf "ge-" verlangt: "hat gemacht" oder "er hat losgelassen". In deinem Beispiel wird ja "lassen" ins Perfekt gesetzt, so weit hast du einen guten Grund, warum du "gelassen" erwartest – allerdings hast du in deiner Variante das Perfekt-"haben" verloren, dann kann schon mal kein Partizip "gelassen" mehr kommen.
Aber nun die Regel für die richtige Form: In Konstruktionen mit mehreren Verben, wenn ein Modalverb, Kausalverb oder Wahrnehmungsverb ins Perfekt gesetzt wird, erscheint ausnahmsweise der einfache Infinitiv als Perfektform, nicht das Partizip ("Ersatzinfinitiv") (zB. Dudengrammatik 2022, S. 396). Vergleiche:

Er hat es nicht gekonnt.
Er hat es nicht machen können (Folge aus mehreren Verben)

oder

Er hätte den Ball losgelassen

Er hätte den Ball fallen lassen (mehrere Verben)

Genauso:  "er hätte es verrecken lassen",

... oder "...würde haben verrecken lassen"


Zuguterletzt hast du einen Nebensatz und alle Verben stehen am Satzende, allerdings hier in einer etwas verqueren Reihenfolge. Diese ein wenig vorgezogene Position von "würde + haben" (aber immer noch bei Endstellung des ganzen Prädikats) heißt Oberfeld. Eine ausführliche Erläuterung findet sich in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Reihenfolge_der_Verben (am Ende dieses Textes wird auch ein Beispiel mit "würde haben" erläutert).

This is not true at all: the "Ersatzinfinitiv" is not an "Infinitiv" at all but in fact a Partizip Perfekt with a missing suffix "ge-", because the perfective aspect is only marked once.

Example: "er hat es gekonnt" - Participle without ge- would be "konnt", Ersatzinfinitiv however: "hat es machen können".

Sigh: "ich bin gesehen worden". Infinitive would be: "ich bin gesehen werden". Yes, in some cases the participle with the missing "ge-" has been (mis-)reinterpreted as an Infinitiv, but if you look colsely how the German Perfekt has developed you will understand exactly this mechanism to be in place.

That's purely historical. In modern German, the ge- participle does not encode prefectivity. A symptom for this is that, at some point, even inherently perfective verbs started taking the ge-prefix, which they originally didn't need: old "er ist kommen" - today: "er ist gekommen". - How do you explain the stark difference between the participle "gekonnt" and the Ersatzinfinitiv "können"?

Furthermore, your example "worden" is not an Ersatzinfinitive in the sense of contemporary grammar, because there is no alternation. (Passive auxiliary and copula (with its participle "geworden") are different verbs).

What do you mean by ""there is no alternation"? "Ich bin [attribute] geworden" vs. "ich bin [PPP] worden". Where do you mean that "worden" comes from? I just used this verb because the difference between infinitive and PPP with "ge-" is obvious, in other verbs the PPP without "ge-" just looks like the infinitve. Just compare with the equivalent English constructions (as Middle English diminished the Old English "ge-" to "y-" and the dropped it completely in modern English (with the noticeable exception of the PP "yclept").

"Ersatzinfinitiv" = "infinitivus pro participio" means that infinitive and participial forms alternate in different constructions with the same verb (in the same language)  – let's not mix up the grammar of a language with the history of a language...Different historical stages of a language are almost like different languages.
